# Closest point on a line segment to an AABB

Tags: line, closest, segment, aabb

I need to know the point on a line segment that is closest to an AABB.  I know that the line definitely does not intersect the box.

As a possible simplification, one of the dimensions of the box is zero (most of the time) so finding the closest point on the line segment to one face is all that I need. (I could extend this to check all 6 faces of the AABB in the edge case)

Just to confirm

- The line is not infinite, it is defined by two points
- The box/face is also constrained and not infinite

Comment: Since this was asked in the holidays, I just thought I'd give it a quick bump to see if anyone has any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution to this.  I find the closest point on each of the 12 edges of the box (assuming full 3D box) and I also clamp each end of the line segment to the box and evaluate the distance from the segment. I then choose the closest out of these 14 points which seems to work.  The reason for the 2 additional clamp points is when the line segment is constrained within 2 dimensions of the box, e.g. think of a lollipop, the closest point is not on one of the edges in this example.

Comment: Could do a plane intersect against the 6 planes